# User data T object operator error

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

```
    global $wpdb;
    $wp_users = $wpdb->prefix . 'users';
    $users = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT id, user_email FROM $wp_users;");


    //$user11 = get_userdata(2);
    //$capabilities11 = $user11->{$wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities'};

        foreach($users as $u){
            $userdata = get_userdata($u->id);
            $capabilities = $userdata->{wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities'};
        }
```

The code gives me: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_OBJECT_OPERATOR in /home.../asd.php on line

```
$capabilities = $userdata->{wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities'};
```

When I however use

```
$user11 = get_userdata(2);
$capabilities11 = $user11->{$wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities'};
```

everything works fine. Does anyone know what's going on and how to fix this?

Comment: What php version do you have?

Comment: See the possible duplicate there is your answer!

Comment: Nope, it was a syntax mistake, as somebody pointed out before, but has just deleted the post. Should be $wpdb instead of wpdb.